# PHP simple html dom damaging indentation

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP simple html dom to edit some html files. The problem is that when I save, it deletes all carriage returns. How can I preserve them?
Thanks

Comment: What editor are you using to edit subsequent files?

Comment: I use simple html dom to change innertext of a div with some plain text I provide. Then I save().

Comment: ...and how do you know carriage returns are missing, what do text editor are you finding this in?

Comment: @Marcel It can't be a problem connected to text editor. I use the same (gedit), before and after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API documentation doesn't show them, but `file_get_html` and `str_get_html` functions have a bunch of extra fun parameters, just open up `simple_html_dom.php`:

```
function file_get_html(
  $url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1,
  $maxLen=-1,
  $lowercase = true,
  $forceTagsClosed=true,
  $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET,
  $stripRN=true,
  $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)

function str_get_html(
  $str,
  $lowercase=true,
  $forceTagsClosed=true,
  $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET,
  $stripRN=true,
  $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
```

Maybe you could set `$stripRN` to false, which would otherwise do this in `simple_html_dom->prepare()`:

```
//before we save the string as the doc...  strip out the \r \n's if we are told to.
if ($stripRN) {
    $str = str_replace("\r", " ", $str);
    $str = str_replace("\n", " ", $str);
}
```